# regular expressions, the meaning of curly braces

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working on some python code, and it uses the "re" python package to search for an item with a regular expression pattern in a given list of items.

While I was looking into the code, I encountered something I cannot understand about curly braces of the regular expression.

The code fragment is like this.

```
regex = re.search("mov .* ptr \[(?P<dst>([(rax)|(rbx)|(rcx)|(rdx)|(rsi)|(rdi)|(r9)|(r10)|(r11)|(r12)|(r13)|(r14)|(r15)]{3}))\], (?P<src>([(rax)|(rbx)|(rcx)|(rdx)|(rsi)|(rdi)|(r9)|(r10)|(r11)|(r12)|(r13)|(r14)|(r15)]{3}))$", f)
```

f is a given input and looks like this.

regex becomes 1, I printed the content of f, and it shows like this.

"mov qword ptr [rsi], rdi"

What I can't understand is the curly braces in the regular expression, which in this case "{3}". 
As far as I understand, the curly braces with only one number 'n' are used to indicate that the preceding expression needs to appear exactly 'n' times in order to match (three times in my case).
(for instance, ab{3} would result in abbb to match)

So, if that is correct, I think one of "(rax), (rbx), (rcx), etc.." needs to appear exactly three times in order to match, but regarding the content of f shown above, that is not the case.

So I was wondering what point I am missing and how I can understand the curly braces in the regular expression above.

Comment: number of repetition of  literals/charectors

Comment: Can you provide a test string that is fed into the search method?

Comment: This regex "works" due to the wrong use of a character class. `[(rax)|(rbx)|(rcx)|(rdx)|(rsi)|(rdi)|(r9)|(r10)|(r11)|(r12)|(r13)|(r14)|(r15)]` is just matching one of the characters inside.

Comment: You might want to rewrite your pattern as `mov .*? ptr \[(?P<dst>r(?:[abcd]x|[sd]i|9|1[012345]))\], (?P<src>r(?:[abcd]x|[sd]i|9|1[012345]))$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided regex is using square brackets incorrectly. Brackets denote a set of characters, and so a `{3}` after those characters indicates any combination of three of those characters will match. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), under `[]`.

I believe the correct regex would be something like:

```
regex = re.search(
    'mov .* ptr '
    '\[(?P<dst>(rax|rbx|rcx|rdx|rsi|rdi|r9|r10|r11|r12|r13|r14|r15))\], '
    '(?P<src>(rax|rbx|rcx|rdx|rsi|rdi|r9|r10|r11|r12|r13|r14|r15))$', f)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a bogus regular expression.  It doesn't do quite what whoever wrote it meant it to do.

To demonstrate this, I fed it an invalid input:

```
$ python2
...
>>> s = ("mov .* ptr \[(?P<dst>([(rax)|(rbx)|(rcx)|(rdx)|"
... "(rsi)|(rdi)|(r9)|(r10)|(r11)|(r12)|(r13)|(r14)|"
... "(r15)]{3}))\], (?P<src>([(rax)|(rbx)|(rcx)|(rdx)|"
... "(rsi)|(rdi)|(r9)|(r10)|(r11)|(r12)|(r13)|(r14)|(r15)]{3}))$")
>>> import re
>>> r2 = re.search(s, "mov qword ptr [r5i], rdi")
>>> r2
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x800684ca8>
>>> r2.group('dst')
'r5i'
>>> r2 = re.search(s, "mov qword ptr [(5i], rdi")
>>> r2.group('dst')
'(5i'
>>>
```

It's difficult to say what went through the mind of whoever wrote the expression, and how they came up with what they eventually used.  You are correct, though, that the `{3}` means "repeat exactly three times".

Comment: I guess the regular expression is not bogus, but good enough for their usecase because if you hae `[(5i]` in your disassemby code you'll have a problem somewhere else already. If you wrote the code by hand, then it will not have compiled anyway...

Comment: @RedX: "good enough" would depend on what this is being used for. In any case it's not a very *sensible* regexp. The one in Karin's answer is clear and correct, and the one in Sebastian Proske's comment is compact and correct.

Answer (score 0):

The others have answered it correctly, I just show you a way to visualize/test your regex patterns.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WOX4TAA8eqlEp69E)

Comment: That diagram is for the *corrected* regex from [Karin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38824311/20938).  It would be more helpful if you included a diagram of the original, broken regex for comparison--unfortunately, that image is a yard wide ([literally!](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WOX4TAA8eqlEp69E)).